# mysql group by confusion

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

so i have this table;

mysql> describe player_weapon_stats;

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| players_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| weapons_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| matches_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hits       | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| shots      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| kills      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| acc        | decimal(4,2)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

with lots of rows (currently around 400k) like this;

mysql> select * from player_weapon_stats ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5;

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | players_id | weapons_id | matches_id | hits | shots | kills | acc   |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |          1 |          1 |    5 |     0 |     1 |  0.00 |
|  2 |          1 |          2 |          1 |  133 |   437 |     2 | 30.43 |
|  3 |          1 |          3 |          1 |  247 |   896 |     8 | 27.57 |
|  4 |          1 |          4 |          1 |    0 |    11 |     0 |  0.00 |
|  5 |          1 |          5 |          1 |   35 |    59 |     9 | 59.32 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

so multiple weapon stats per player per match are recorded

what im trying to do is to get the highest acc for each weapon_id based on the sum total of each player

the returned rows should be equal in count to the number of weapons (in this case 8)

this is what i tried;

```
mysql> SELECT players_id, weapons_id, SUM(hits) AS hits, SUM(shots) AS shots, SUM(kills) AS kills, (FORMAT(hits / shots, 4) * 100) AS acc FROM player_weapon_stats GROUP BY weapons_id ORDER BY acc DESC;
// no player association so SUM totals up all players together

mysql> SELECT players_id, weapons_id, SUM(hits) AS hits, SUM(shots) AS shots, SUM(kills) AS kills, (FORMAT(hits / shots, 4) * 100) AS acc FROM player_weapon_stats GROUP BY weapons_id, players_id ORDER BY acc DESC, weapons_id ASC LIMIT 10;
// incorrect acc and around 25k rows returned

mysql> SELECT players_id, weapons_id, SUM(hits) AS hits, SUM(shots) AS shots, SUM(kills) AS kills, (FORMAT(hits / shots, 4) * 100) AS acc FROM player_weapon_stats GROUP BY players_id, weapons_id ORDER BY acc DESC, weapons_id ASC;
// appears correct acc, and correct totals but returns around 25k rows as well
```

ive tried a lot of variations of the above and whatever else came to mind at the time but im still stuck.. i think ive been staring at it too long

can anybody help me out?

---- edit

the sample data i used is a bit too small to compile into results as there would be multiple entries for each weapons_id for each players_id which then would be added together to form an "average/overall" for that player/weapon;

http://pastebin.com/Q1N5mScU

as you see its added up totals for each weapon for the 4 players.. so the expected result would be similar to that but simply one row per weapon

im not sure how else to explain it

---- 2nd edit

```
mysql> SELECT players_id, weapons_id, MAX(acc) FROM (SELECT weapons_id, players_id, AVG(acc) AS acc FROM player_weapon_stats GROUP BY players_id, weapons_id) AS t1 GROUP BY weapons_id;
    +------------+------------+-----------+
    | players_id | weapons_id | MAX(acc)  |
    +------------+------------+-----------+
    |          1 |          0 | 25.000000 |
    |          1 |          1 |  0.000000 |
    |          1 |          2 | 84.995000 |
    |          1 |          3 | 99.990000 |
    |          1 |          4 | 99.990000 |
    |          1 |          5 | 94.290000 |
    |          1 |          6 | 70.250000 |
    |          1 |          7 | 99.990000 |
    |          1 |          8 | 99.990000 |
    +------------+------------+-----------+
    9 rows in set (0.33 sec)
```

---- 3rd edit

what appears to be the solution based on jcrummacks queries;

```
mysql> SELECT players_id, weapons_id, hits, shots, kills, MAX(acc) FROM ( SELECT players_id, weapons_id, SUM(hits) AS hits, SUM(shots) AS shots, SUM(kills) AS kills, AVG(acc) AS acc FROM player_weapon_stats GROUP BY players_id, weapons_id ORDER BY weapons_id ASC, AVG(acc) DESC) AS t1 GROUP BY weapons_id;
+------------+------------+------+-------+-------+-----------+
| players_id | weapons_id | hits | shots | kills | MAX(acc)  |
+------------+------------+------+-------+-------+-----------+
|        202 |          0 |    1 |     3 |     0 | 25.000000 |
|       1544 |          1 |    1 |     0 |     0 |  0.000000 |
|       3034 |          2 |    8 |    11 |     0 | 84.995000 |
|        952 |          3 |   16 |    16 |     0 | 99.990000 |
|       3493 |          4 |    1 |     1 |     0 | 99.990000 |
|        839 |          5 |   33 |    35 |     2 | 94.290000 |
|        734 |          6 |  366 |   521 |     5 | 70.250000 |
|       2643 |          7 |    1 |     1 |     0 | 99.990000 |
|       3227 |          8 |    1 |     1 |     0 | 99.990000 |
+------------+------------+------+-------+-------+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.72 sec)
```

Comment: It's not making sense to me, but it would be easier if you posted expected results based on the example data you posted.

Comment: so do you want one row per weapons_id, together with the maximum acc achieved by any player and the ID of the player who achieved it? (And what if more than one player achieves the maximum?)

Comment: yes that is pretty much it.. but it should be the maximum AVERAGE accuracy based on however many matches the player has played in (1-1000+).. if the player has played in 10 matches then they have 10 entries for each weapon.. so they would be added/averaged then i get the maximum acc from those numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sort of reading between the lines here of what i think your looking for and also assuming your on a fairly recent version of mysql (needs derived table support) even if i'm not quite on what your looking for maybe this will point you in the right direction.

```
select
  players_id,
  weapons_id,
  max(acc)
from (
  select
    weapons_id,
    players_id,
    avg (acc) as acc
  from
    player_weapon_stats
  group by
    players_id,
    weapons_id
  order by 
    weapons_id asc, 
    avg(acc) desc) as t1
group by 
  weapons_id
```

hopefully i'm going in the direction you were trying to go.

Comment: this is the direction im going but it still seems to fail at getting the correct players_id.. altho it appears that the acc is correct (most come out at 99% which is about right)

Comment: you want the players_id too should just be a tweak to select weapons_id, players_id, max(acc) from ( select weapons_id, players_id, avg (acc) as acc from player_weapon_stats group by players_id, weapons_id) as t1 group by weapons_id

Comment: changed the initial answer above to include the players_id in the output also

Comment: well yes i tried adding the players_id but it comes out incorrect (see the new edit on main post)

Comment: strange mysql seems to not return the corresponding players_id along with the weapons_id, max(acc) which is what i would have expected it to return, instead it just seems to be picking the 1st.

Comment: can you try again with the sql above i've added an order by into the sub select

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want one row per weapon, with the maximum accuracy achieved by any player. If so, try the following:

```
SELECT weapons_id, 
       SUM(hits) AS hits, 
       SUM(shots) AS shots, 
       SUM(kills) AS kills, 
       MAX(acc) AS acc 
FROM (SELECT players_id, 
             weapons_id, 
             SUM(hits) AS hits, 
             SUM(shots) AS shots, 
             SUM(kills) AS kills, 
             FORMAT(SUM(hits) / SUM(shots), 4) * 100 AS acc 
      FROM player_weapon_stats 
      GROUP BY players_id, weapons_id) SQ
GROUP BY weapons_id
```

Comment: one row per weapon with the maximum average acc by any player over however many matches theyve been involved in.. your query seems to return total stats for all players combined and like jcrummack's it doesnt return the correct players_id

Comment: @minky: my query should be returning the the maximum accuracy achieved by any one player, together with the total values for *all* players.

Comment: ok but what i actually need the query to return is not only the max acc for each weapon but also the details associated with that acc (the details being the total hits/shots/kills for that specific players_id/weapons_id)

maybe if you view the site you may understand what im trying (poorly) to explain

http://minky.mine.nu/cpmpickup/stats